# Convert from GSAP Jquery to GSAP Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsap

I need to change this -

```
$(function() {

    $(".nav-1").hover(function() {
            TweenMax.to($(this), 0.2, {scale:1.2});
        },
        function() {
            TweenMax.to($(this), 0.2, {scale:1});
        }

    );

});
```

Into Javascript?

This is my html -

```
<h1 id="animate1">
    <div class="nav-1">T</div>
    <div class="nav-1">R</div>
    <div class="nav-1">U</div>
    <div class="nav-1">S</div>
    <div class="nav-1">T</div>
    <div class="nav-1">E</div>
    <div class="nav-1">D</div> 
    <div class="nav-1">S</div>
    <div class="nav-1">E</div>
    <div class="nav-1">R</div>
    <div class="nav-1">V</div>
    <div class="nav-1">I</div>
    <div class="nav-1">C</div>
    <div class="nav-1">E</div>
</h1>
```

Is there any way for the animation to cycle through the letters without having to hover over each letter?

Any help would be greatly received.

Answer (score 0):

**Jquery to pure javascript:**

In your javascript code block following is an shorthand of jquery `$(document).ready` function.

```
$(function() {
    // this will execute after document is ready
});
```

Here is [document ready equivalent without jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery).

You can use `mouseenter` & `mouseleave` events instead of jquery hover function.

**Animation circle through without hover:**

http://jsfiddle.net/shishirmorshed/ke24sagj/

Answer (score 0):

This should be a very easy process for you. You can use this for Rollovers:
    document.getElementById("yourObject").addEventListener("mouseover", rollOverAni);
    document.getElementById("yourObject").addEventListener("mouseleave", rollOutAni);

and as far as using GSAP, you can easily enter items the exact way as Jquery, for example:
TweenMax.set("#MyBox", {left:"-100%"});

--cheers

Comment: Thanks for participating at stackoverflow. It seems to be a good answer, so why not make it better by editing it and applying some formatting to the code blocks. You can find out more at http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help